# Rails partial generator of template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator

Is there a way in rails, that I can only generate templates partially?

For example in my generators/generatorName/templates folder, there is template1.html.erb and template2.html.erb files

in console when I run the command

rails g generatorName

It will just generate by default the template1,html.erb.

and if I want to add the another template, how can I do that? Is there a way?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a custom generator. You'll need to create/copy the second file on invoke.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html